# How to filter Kendo Ui Grid with DateRange?

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-ui

Currently I am using Kendo Ui Grid and I try to filter by [DateRange](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/filtering/reusable-filter/#toc-filtering-by-date-ranges). At the moment my code goes like this:

HTML:

```
<kendo-grid-column field="createdate" title="Creation Date" width="150">
 <ng-template kendoGridFilterCellTemplate let-filter>
  <app-date-range-filter-cell class="date-range-filter" [filter]="filter" field="createdate">
  </app-date-range-filter-cell> 
 </ng-template>
</kendo-grid-column>
```

In my response I have `createdate: "2019-04-19T15:47:48.000+0000"` and I show it in my Grid like this `createdate: "19/04/2019, 18:47:48"` using:

```
this.createdate = this.datePipe.transform(this.createdate, 'dd/MM/yyyy, HH:mm:ss');
```

I need make filtering by `DateRange` works only by date because Kendo DateRange works with type `Date` and mine is type `string`. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I have found my solution here. I did the following steps:

a) Converted `string` dates into type `Date` with:

```
this.createdate = new Date(this.createdate);
```

b) I changed the format of date in my html like that:

```
<kendo-grid-column field="createdate" title="Creation Date" width="150" format="{0: dd/MM/yyyy, HH:mm:ss}">
  <ng-template kendoGridFilterCellTemplate let-filter>
    <app-date-range-filter-cell class="date-range-filter" [filter]="filter" field="createdate">
    </app-date-range-filter-cell>
  </ng-template>
</kendo-grid-column>
```

And voila you can use `DateRange` for column with dates in Kendo Ui Grid.